# How to Add a webbrowser into popup in windows phone (code behind)

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-phone-7

Below is the code snippet i am using to add a web-browser into a pop up control but does not seem to work .

```
       Popup codePopup = new Popup();
        StackPanel test = new StackPanel();
        WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();
        wb1.Navigated += wb1_Navigated;
        wb1.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://www.google.com"));
        test.Children.Add(wb1);
        test.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        test.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        codePopup.Child = test;
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(codePopup);
        codePopup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: have to set the height and width of the webbrowser control

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height and width of the webbrowser control.